# Easier way to check if a string contains only one type of letter in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a string `'829383&&*&@<<<<>><>GG'`. I want a way to measure if a string has only one type of letter. For example the string above would return True, because it only has two Gs, but this string, `'829383&&*&@<<<<>><>GGAa'` would not. I've been iteratively going through the string having made it into an array. I was hoping someone knew an easier way.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by "type of letter". Why do you care about the A's in the second string but not the digits and symbols in the first one?

Comment: Guessing, because A's are letters and digits and symbols aren't.

Answer (score 2):

use `filter` with `str.isalpha` function to create a sublist containing only letters, then create a set. Final length must be one or your condition isn't met.

```
v="829383&&&@<<<<>><>GG"

print(len(set(filter(str.isalpha,v)))==1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Jean-Francois's answer is what I'd actually use 99% of the time, but for cases where the string is *huge* you might want a solution that will return as soon as the second unique character is detected, instead of finishing processing:

```
from future_builtins import map, filter  # Only on Py2, to get lazy map/filter

from itertools import groupby, islice
from operator import itemgetter

# Remove non-alphas, then reduce consecutive identical alphabetic characters
# to a single instance of that character
lets = map(itemgetter(0), groupby(filter(str.isalpha, somestr)))

# Skip the first result, and if we find a second, then there was more than one
# in the string
if next(islice(lets, 1, None), None) is not None:
   # There were at least two unique alphabetic characters
else:
   # There were only 0-1 unique alphabetic characters
```

Distinguishing no alphabetic from one alphabetic could instead be done without `islice` as:

```
atleastone = next(lets, None) is not None
multiple = next(lets, None) is not None
```